# What is a Lua State?

Tags: function, lua

I need to know because I supposedly need to know what it is to make a Lua global using lua_setglobal().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Brief example which may help...

```c
lua_State* L=lua_open();           // create a Lua state
luaL_openlibs(L);                  // load standard libs 

lua_pushstring(L, "nick");         // push a string on the stack
lua_setglobal(L, "name");          // set the string to the global 'name'

luaL_loadstring(L, "print(name)"); // load a script
lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);             // call the script
```

Comment: Do you know why there might be multiple `lua_State` objects in a program? [I need help with this question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080633/can-i-load-additional-functions-in-base-open-without-breaking-lua-state). As I stated [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4201531/826983), I think that there should be a value set for `L->l_G->_defaultmeta.value.gc` at the time I steal the pointer to the `lua_State` struct, but for some reason non of the stolen structs does have it set.

Answer (score 11):

You'll want to check out this page in Programming in Lua: [A first example](http://www.lua.org/pil/24.1.html) To make an analogy, pretend that the C or C++ program is running in a little box and has access to its functions, variables, and so on.  The lua_State is basically a way to access what's going on in the Lua "box" during execution of your program and allows you to glue the two languages together.

Comment: Can you tell, why there might be multiple `lua_State` objects in a program? I am currently trying to hook into the Lua initialization process and I now discovered that there are at least 3 different `lua_State` objects. What I don't understand - and this [has to do with my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41080633/can-i-load-additional-functions-in-base-open-without-breaking-lua-state) - is why `L->l_G->_defaultmeta.value.gc` is *always* `NULL`. All three structs get by and none of them have a value set at that time. But this can't be, because the original Lua code looks like

Comment: as if they should have set a value at this stage of the initialization process. Any help would be great!